# Media3 ExoPlayer, setup background playing

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to implement background working ExoPlayer.

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

lateinit var controllerFeat: MediaController

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContent {
        TestMediaBackgroundServiceTheme {

            val mediaItem by
                remember {
                    mutableStateOf(
                        MediaItem.Builder()
                            .setMediaId("media-1")
                            .setUri("https://file-examples.com/storage/fe0ecd5dff65a0f7995a949/2017/11/file_example_MP3_1MG.mp3")
                            .build()
                    )
                }

            val sessionToken =
                SessionToken(this@MainActivity, ComponentName(this, PlaybackService::class.java))

            LaunchedEffect(Unit){


                val controllerFuture =
                    MediaController.Builder(this@MainActivity, sessionToken).buildAsync()
                controllerFuture.addListener({

                    controllerFeat = controllerFuture.get()
                    controllerFeat.setMediaItem(mediaItem)
                    controllerFeat.prepare()
                }, MoreExecutors.directExecutor())


            }
            
            Surface(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
            ) {

                Button(onClick = {

                    if (controllerFeat.isPlaying){
                        controllerFeat.pause()
                    }else{
                        controllerFeat.play()
                    }
                }) {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

class PlaybackService : MediaSessionService() {
private var mediaSession: MediaSession? = null

```
override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    val player = ExoPlayer.Builder(this).build()
    mediaSession = MediaSession.Builder(this, player).build()
}

override fun onTaskRemoved(rootIntent: Intent?) {
    val player = mediaSession?.player!!
    if (!player.playWhenReady || player.mediaItemCount == 0) {
        stopSelf()
    }
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    mediaSession?.run {
        player.release()
        release()
        mediaSession = null
    }
    super.onDestroy()
}

override fun onGetSession(controllerInfo: MediaSession.ControllerInfo): MediaSession? =
    mediaSession
```

}

Here My Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MEDIA_PLAYBACK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.TestMediaBackgroundService"
    tools:targetApi="31">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TestMediaBackgroundService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name=".PlaybackService"
        android:foregroundServiceType="mediaPlayback"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="androidx.media3.session.MediaLibraryService"/>
            <action android:name="android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <receiver android:name="androidx.media3.session.MediaButtonReceiver"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
```

But there are several issues, please explain in for me ->

1. If in application i stop playing and close it, notification with song stays active but i cannot continue play song
2. If song playing i close application and all is correct song also playing but when i close application it resets playing to init position, i want continue playing
3. When i play anything else like youtube music my player continues playing but how to set playing priority ?